# Python время не обновляется

Tags: python, время

Всем привет,пишу бота под тг.

Столкнулся с проблемой,при запуске скрипта я получаю день,минуты,и час.

Оно должно обновляться но увы(

Вот кусок кода

```
from datetime import date

import datetime

today=datetime.datetime.now()

times = str(today.hour)+str(':')+str(today.minute)

print(times)

wd=date.weekday(today)

print(wd)

time = str(today.hour)+str('.')+str(today.minute)

print(time)
```

Пытался через  while но идея плохая как по мне.

Comment: и что вы тут надеялись увидеть? если ваш скрипт выполняется за милесекунды, то явно минуты не изменятся

Comment: Я хочу узнать как сделать так что-бы время обновлялось)А скрипт это почти бот)

Comment: Что значит *"время должно обновляться"*?

Comment: Когда запускаю скрипт то в переменную присваивается значение часа и минут.Прошло время а значение осталось)Как сделать чтобы оно изменялось

Comment: Нужно просто заново получать текущее время каждый раз, когда вам нужно его использовать.

Comment: Спасибо,Вы натолкнули меня на ответ))